# Neo4j/GraphQL augmented Schema

Tags: neo4j, graphql, apollo-server

I'm trying to learn a bit about Neo4j's GraphQL integration. I'm using the GrandStack starter which can be found here. [Grand Stack Starter](https://github.com/grand-stack/grand-stack-starter). The starter doesn't use a lot of the boilerplate that you see in other GrapQL applications because, as I understand it, the Neo4j integration is supposed to bypass the need to double declare Schema and Resolvers. It uses Apollo Server and an "augmentedSchema" instead. Using the starter code I've tried to add some mutations to the schema, in this case, a deleteUser mutation. I keep getting an error, saying that the Mutation id defined more than once, when I know I'm only putting it in the code in one place. This is my schema.js:

```
    import { neo4jgraphql } from "neo4j-graphql-js";

export const typeDefs = `
type User {
  id: ID!
  name: String
  friends(first: Int = 10, offset: Int = 0): [User] @relation(name: "FRIENDS", direction: "BOTH")
  reviews(first: Int = 10, offset: Int = 0): [Review] @relation(name: "WROTE", direction: "OUT")
  avgStars: Float @cypher(statement: "MATCH (this)-[:WROTE]->(r:Review) RETURN toFloat(avg(r.stars))")
  numReviews: Int @cypher(statement: "MATCH (this)-[:WROTE]->(r:Review) RETURN COUNT(r)")
}

type Business {
  id: ID!
  name: String
  address: String
  city: String
  state: String
  reviews(first: Int = 10, offset: Int = 0): [Review] @relation(name: "REVIEWS", direction: "IN")
  categories(first: Int = 10, offset: Int =0): [Category] @relation(name: "IN_CATEGORY", direction: "OUT")
}

type Review {
  id: ID!
  stars: Int
  text: String
  business: Business @relation(name: "REVIEWS", direction: "OUT")
  user: User @relation(name: "WROTE", direction: "IN")
}

type Category {
  name: ID!
  businesses(first: Int = 10, offset: Int = 0): [Business] @relation(name: "IN_CATEGORY", direction: "IN")
}

type Query {
    users(id: ID, name: String, first: Int = 10, offset: Int = 0): [User]
    businesses(id: ID, name: String, first: Int = 10, offset: Int = 0): [Business]
    reviews(id: ID, stars: Int, first: Int = 10, offset: Int = 0): [Review]
    category(name: ID!): Category
    usersBySubstring(substring: String, first: Int = 10, offset: Int = 0): [User] @cypher(statement: "MATCH (u:User) WHERE u.name CONTAINS $substring RETURN u")
}

type Mutation {

    deleteUser(id: ID!): User
}

`;

export const resolvers = {
    Query: {
        users: neo4jgraphql,
        businesses: neo4jgraphql,
        reviews: neo4jgraphql,
        category: neo4jgraphql,
        usersBySubstring: neo4jgraphql
    },

    Mutation: {
        deleteUser: neo4jgraphql
    }
};
```

Here's my index:

```
import { typeDefs, resolvers } from "./graphql-schema";
import { ApolloServer, gql, makeExecutableSchema } from "apollo-server";
import { v1 as neo4j } from "neo4j-driver";
import { augmentSchema } from "neo4j-graphql-js";
import dotenv from "dotenv";

dotenv.config();

const schema = makeExecutableSchema({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers
});

// augmentSchema will add autogenerated mutations based on types in schema
const augmentedSchema = augmentSchema(schema);

const driver = neo4j.driver(
    process.env.NEO4J_URI || "bolt://localhost:7687",
    neo4j.auth.basic(
    process.env.NEO4J_USER || "neo4j",
    process.env.NEO4J_PASSWORD || "neo4j"
    )
);

if (driver){
    console.log("Database Connected")
} else{
    console.log("Database Connection Error")
}

const server = new ApolloServer({
  // using augmentedSchema (executable GraphQLSchemaObject) instead of typeDefs and resolvers
  //typeDefs,
  //resolvers,
  context: { driver },
  // remove schema and uncomment typeDefs and resolvers above to use original (unaugmented) schema
  schema: augmentedSchema
});

server.listen(process.env.GRAPHQL_LISTEN_PORT, '0.0.0.0').then(({ url }) => {
  console.log(`GraphQL API ready at ${url}`);
});
```

Error Message: 
[image]

No other code from the starter has been changed. I haven't been able to find much info on the augmentedSchema in the docs. If anyone can point me in the right direction I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 6):

The issue was caused by the augmentedSchema, which automatically creates default mutations for each type i.e. in this case it had already created delete user, update user, and add user. You can see this when you run the GraphiQL server. So I was double declaring the delete user mutation.